# VBA if value in cell display string in other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set some things in my Excel in order to improve my process.
I would like to create a VBA function which let to display value in cell B13 if cell B11 contains "_01_Clients_Particuliers" and cell B12 contains "_00".
These cells are dropdown list.

I never use VBA up to now.

I could write into the cell B13 :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B11,"_01_Clients_Particuliers"),"_100PRD05","")
```

But I need to take into account two cells and I assume I need to use VBA to do that, because the cell B14 has already a formula : `=INDIRECT(B13)`

[image]

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you drop-down list only contain few selection, then the following formula should be work for you.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H1,C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H2,C2))),"It is there","not found")
```

[image]

In addition, you will write the range reference directly, it will return error in my case

[image]

Comment: If I look your example with C3's cell, I already have a formula with 'INDIRECT'. How I can add another formula into this dropdown list to display directly the element ?

Comment: @Essex He say the formula is in B14, rather than B13 right?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, I don't think you need VBA to do this.
Check out [Using IF with AND, OR and NOT functions](http://Unless%20I%27ve%20misunderstood%20your%20question,%20I%20don%27t%20think%20you%20need%20VBA%20to%20do%20this.%20https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)
Again, apologies if I'm mistaken, but it seems that your desired result could be produced with the following formula in B13:

```excel
IF(AND(B11 = "_01_Clients_Particuliers", B12 = "_00"), "_100PRD05","")
```

This will put the value "_100PRD05" in `B13` if `B11` equals "_01_Clients_Particuliers" *and* `B12` equals "_00".

Comment: B11, B12 and B13 are dropdown lists. So I can't add formula because I've already validation data into these cases with INDIRECT formula.

Comment: Can you show the formulas you're using to put values into B11-13? Logical tests like `IF`, `AND`, etc. still work if the value of a cell is produced with `INDIRECT`, so if these formulas aren't working for you there must be some other reason I didn't understand properly